# Best practice to communicate the existence of different tiers of access /membership on a Shopify website

Tags: design-patterns, e-commerce

My website has an invite-only section for a subset of account-holders. 
What would be the best way to make that understood to my users? Are there any design patterns that have been proven their usefulness in managing the expectations of multiple sets of users with different access privileges?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what the privileges are of course, but many sites do this. For example:

[image]

If you are a 'Prime' member you clearly have access to free shipping and a price discount.

You might also want to explain why it is invite-only